# How to get primary key of selected column in row in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have the below table. I want to select 30 pieces of Product Code **011A** from the table. Each row contains a number of pieces, in the column `PCS`. I want to select the 30 pieces in FIFO order based on date, and return the number of pieces selected from each row, so I'll need to know the primary key value for each row that has pieces selected from it. For example, from this data:

```
Key   Product Code     PCS   Date
 1      011A           10    2015-07-01
 2      011B           20    2015-07-01
 3      011C           20    2015-07-01
 4      011A           12    2015-07-02
 5      011A           40    2015-07-03
 6      011D           60    2015-07-04 
 7      011A           20    2015-07-04
```

Selecting 30 pieces of product code "011A" should give an output table like:

```
Key   Product Code     PCS   DATE
 1      011A           10    2015-07-01
 4      011A           12    2015-07-02
 5      011A           8     2015-07-03
```

You can see that the total number of pieces is 30, and that the maximum number of pieces were selected from the rows with primary key 1 and 4, because they're the first dates. Only 8 were selected from row #5, because it's the next in date order, and only 8 is needed to reach 30 total. Row #7 wasn't needed, so it doesn't show up in the result.

How can I write a query to accomplish this?

Comment: Why is key 7 not in the result? If you add the values of PCS where ProductCode = 011A you don't get 30. Why is the value for key 5 changed from 40 to 8??? Your desired output doesn't match the sample OR there are some business rules that you haven't shared. We can help but we need to know the whole problem.

Comment: i have update the question lease look into it. I am following FIFO method to select the PCS quantity. and 8 Quantity is selected from 40 and remaining is 32. But i am not showing remaining quantity.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Could you please clarify one case: if you have for example two product codes "011A" per one day, will we use both or how will we choose correct product?

Comment: We have to use FIFO method on Date to select the product code to complete the quantity.. We will do order by on date in desc that will implement the FIFO and then we select the quantity to complete the quantity either we have two product code 011A on the same day or different day

Comment: @Sean Lange....I am waiting for your solution.

Comment: Why not use the excellent solution that Gordon posted? I am not here to do your work for you so saying you are waiting for my solution is not going to generate much effort from me.

Comment: hey...in your previous comment you say that you can help me. I am not saying that you do my home work and that's not my home work. Its just scenario which i generate. But still unable to find the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2012, you can use cumulative sum:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(pcs) over (partition by productcode order by date) as cumepcs
      from thetable t
      where productcode = '011A'
     ) t
where cumepcs - pcs < 30;
```

Doing a cumulative sum in SQL Server 2008 is a bit more work.  Here is one way:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select sum(t2.pcs) 
              from thetable t2
              where t2.productcode = t.productcode and
                    t2.date <= t.date
             ) as cumepcs
      from thetable t
      where productcode = '011A'
     ) t
where cumepcs - pcs < 30;
```

EDIT:

If you want the allocated amounts from each bucket, you need to tweak the size of the last bucket.  Change the `select` to:

```
select t.*,
       (case when cume_pcs <= 30 then pcs
             else 30 - (cumepcs - pcs)
        end) as allocated_pcs
. . .
```

Comment: @SyedZunair . . . I see.  It was giving the last key in the sequence that added to 30.  I just changed the logic so it should give all the rows.

Comment: Now it is giving me three rows with correct primary keys but quantity in last row is 40 but i require 8.

Comment: Did you think that it will work for all Product code? Product code and PCS quantity can be vary.

Comment: @SyedZunair . . . This should work for all product codes.